# Rails idiom for .present? and .any?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a Rails/Ruby idiom for checking if an enumerable is both present and has non-`nil` values?

I get errors if I ever try to do `nil.any?` so I always have to do `if foo && foo.any?`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `try` method provided by ActiveSupport:

```
obj.try(:any?)
```

This will evaluate to `nil` if `obj.nil?` or to `false` if `obj` is an empty collection, so in both cases it will evaluate to a falsy value in a boolean context.

Comment: Just a note that this requires ActiveSupport (since the question said "Rails/Ruby" rather than just Rails).

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, it's Rails-specific.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can now use the safe navigation operator:

```
if foo&.any?
```

Comment: Just to elaborate on this, the safe navigation operator is available in Ruby >= 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the andand gem:

```
foo.andand.any?
```